# Autofac. RegisterType after .Build and register/resolve list

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, autofac

Have two questions

1. How correct builder.RegisterType(..) after ApplicationContainer = 
   builder.Build()

builder.Update(ApplicationContainer) is Obsolete

```cs
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    builder.RegisterType<DB>();
    ApplicationContainer = builder.Build();
}

public void Configure()
{
   //Get list of types assigned from IPlugin
   List<Type> types = PluginLoader.LoadPlugins(); <--- will need DB registered early
   foreach (var item in plugins)
   {
       builder.RegisterType(item);
   }
   builder.Update(ApplicationContainer); <-- .Update() is Obsolete
}
```

2. How get all IPlugin

```cs
public Manage(DB _db, IEnumerable<IPlugin> plugins)
{
}
```

3. Resolve by type in any place

```cs
public void Manage(Type type)
{
  var IPlugin plugin = (IPlugin) GlobalResolve.Resolve(type);
}
```

Comment: Updating your existing configuration after it has been built is a bad idea, that's why that method is obsolete. You should move the loading of your plugins to the ConfigureServices method.

Comment: @Steven I need DB (and other registered) in PluginLoaderbuilder.RegisterType<DB>();

Comment: Create the `PluginLoader` manually inside `ConfigureServices`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need IoC for the pluginloader.

However, if you insist I would seperate the responsibilities in two seperate containers. One container which will have all the bits needed to find plugin types and another container which is used by your application for the 'normal' duties. During app startup you use the initialization container to create the other container.

What you can also do is use the container which houses the pluginloader and use that to create another container.

```
        using (var applicationScopeContainer = _initializationContainer.BeginLifetimeScope(
             builder =>
             {
                 //register your new stuff here, resolve dependencies via _initializationContainer
             }))
        {
            //resolve all depenencies via applicationScopeContainer
        }
```